# IBM BPM unable to detect WODM server?

Tags: soap, integration, business-process-management

Following the tutorial on

http://bpmwiki.blueworkslive.com/display/samples/Decision+Service+demonstrating+BPM+and+WODM+integration#DecisionServicedemonstratingBPMandWODMintegration-PartI%26nbsp%3B%5C%26nbsp%3BImplementingtheJRulesSolution

I'm able to run the rule app using soapUI and everything works fine. Now, when I try to implement the rule service on BPM, it seems BPM is unable to detect the WODM server.

When I test this using soapUI, the wsdl URL was something like: `http://localhost:9081/xxxxxxxx`.

Now, when I try to implement this on BPM, I've set the Server location to `http://localhost:9081` and `SOAP Port` to `8881` as shown below:

[image]

However, I've failed to login. I'm wondering **what SOAP Port actually is and why BPM needs one and soapUI doesn't?**

**Update:**
When I set the `SOAP Port` to 8881, it's throwing

```
java.io.IOException: Mismatched serialization UIDs : 
Source(RepId RMI:java.lang.Throwable:F...............) =........ whereas Target (RepId RMI:com.ibm.jsse2.util.h:CAAC186..................) = D9CE.........
```

When I set the `SOAP Port` to 8880, it's not throwing any errors **but there's no ruleset and ruleapp available**

When I set the `SOAP Port` to 8882 and above, it's throwing me

```
[SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV; msg=Error opening socket:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; targetException: Connection 
refused: connect; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
```

Comment: The error when using port 8882 is clearly down to the fact that the port does not exist, so that can be discounted right away. And when you use port 8880, it's connecting but to a WAS that does not have ODM deployed or any rules sets deployed to ODM if it has been deployed. That leaves port 8881. It looks like to me the two servers are possibly running different Java versions, therefore it cannot serialise objects between BPM and ODM?

Comment: @JustinPhillips: I'm sorry if this question is too dumb. Following the site: http://webspherehelp.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-find-version-of-websphere-java.html, I can use `c:\WebSphere\AppServer\versionInfo.bat` but I can only see information related to my BPM. I couldn't find the WAS for my ODM.. **May I know how to find the WAS for ODM?**

Comment: look at your BPM servers definition on the WAS Console, and look at the port definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Has your WAS been installed using the default ports or custom ports?

I have got this working using BPM 8.5 and ODM 8.5, but the default SOAP port is 8880 (although I have noticed that you are using port 9081, which implies you might have more than one WAS server installed so its bumped all the port numbers up by one, so this might not be the problem).

The other thing to check is how you have set up the BPM server in the Process App Settings in BPM. The format of the server location should be http://:

Comment: I've tried to set the server location to `http://localhost/9081` and `http://127.0.0.1:9081` but both negative. The testing environment came with two WAS server using default port

Answer (score 0):

BPM need the SOAP port of WODM server to explore what rule app / rule set are available, so that BPM could present a list for you to choose from.

When you call a ruleset in soapUI like following, you have already specified which rule app / rule set to call in the URL.

https://HOST:PORT/DecisionService/ws/ruleapp/ruleset

You may go to WAS admin console to check what's the SOAP port of the server that running WODM.